# Check that an ID' in a Column have no particulate value in another column at the same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, filter, distinct

I have a salary table with salarySumId, salaryYear and I want to make a select query that find the salarySumIds that do not have 2020-01-01 at all.

my query looks like this

```
select distinct  salarySumId, salaryYear 
from Salary
```

this qyery returns something like this

```
salarySumId     salaryYear 
-----------     ------------
4593086         2019-01-01 
4593093         2018-01-01 
4593093         2019-01-01 
4593093         2020-01-01 
4593094         2019-01-01 
4593095         2018-01-01 
4593095         2019-01-01 
4593095         2020-01-01 
4593096         2017-01-01 
4593096         2018-01-01 
4593096         2019-01-01 
4593096         2020-01-01
```

When I write a query that filter 2020-01-01 as following:

```
select distinct  salarySumId, salaryYear 
from Salary 
where Salary.InsuranceYear < '2020-01-01'

alarySumId      salaryYear 
-----------     ------------
4593086         2019-01-01 
4593093         2018-01-01 
4593093         2019-01-01 
4593094         2019-01-01 
4593095         2018-01-01 
4593095         2019-01-01 
4593096         2017-01-01 
4593096         2018-01-01
```

In reality I just want the query to return (4593086, 4593094)
as they don't have salaryYear value for 2020-01-01 at all.

How to re-write the query to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `case` expression in the `HAVING` clause to count the number of 2020-01-01 rows.

```
select salarySumId
from Salary
group by salarySumId
having sum(case when salaryYear = '2020-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select s.*
from Salary s
where not exists (select 1 
                  from Salary s1 
                  where s1.salarySumId = s.salarySumId and 
                        s1.salaryYear = '2020-01-01'
                );
```